# What determines what direction fish will pull after jumping?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

While fishing, sometimes fish will jump out of the water, which activates a QTE, requiring me to move the left stick left, right, or up. After successfully pulling this off, the fish loses a chunk of stamina as it falls back into the water.

However, many times, I rapidly lose line durability because the fish is suddenly pulling the opposite direction it was prior to jumping.

Does the fish switch directions at random, or can its direction be predicted prior to it landing back in the water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fish will move at random, though I often expect it to go opposite direction and anticipate it rather consistently with a handful of instances which it go the same direction it was headed before it jumped (to be fair, this seems to only happen when the fish is at edge of zone and just switched direction prior to jump).

As an aside I've noticed when the fish drops back in the water, there is often a 1-2 second break where it does nothing and I can reel without consequence.